# Transforming data along (x,y) coordinate axis?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graph, coordinates

I have data  like this

x-axis data values
-20.49, -12.23, -9.99, -1.00 0 , 1.12, 2.23, 3.45, 4.56, 8.99, 20.99, 30.23

y-axis data values
10,20,20,40,50,60........

[image]

I would like to transform above given data into xy coordinate system.

Please have look at the image.

For eg:

along x-axis (min,  max ) data value (-20.49, 30.23),

along y-axis (min,  max ) data value (10,60)

[image]

now if I want plot data(-20.49, 10) in image,
 the X coordinate is going to be =200, 
and Y-coordinate going to be = 220.

Like this I want plot all data fits within the range of rectangle.

Hope this gives all details

Thanks

Comment: Your question is extremely vague and doesn't make sense. Do you want to plot these points in actionscript?

Comment: ok I have edited Q, pls take a look

Comment: Your question still does not make any sense. If you need to map the X and Y values to the given coordinate system, you need to specify how this is supposed to be done. While there are arbitrary ways of doing this, the results make arbitrary sense. Do you in this case, for example, need min(x, y) to map to (200, 220) and max(x, y) to map to (320, 350)?

Comment: look x coordinate starts @ x=200 and ends @ x=320. now difference is 120 along x axis. like the same way y axis difference 130. Now only within in this range I need draw give data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of the math question, not related to any programming language. And speaking about Actionscript 3, it has Y axis going from top to bottom, not from bottom to top. Anyway: If you have two points on an axis that you want to map to screen coordinates of your choice, record `xmin` as lesser native value, `xmax` as greater native value, and coordinates as `xleft` and `xright`. Then, when you need to receive a screen coordinate for your given `x`, you calculate the `xcoord` value as:

```
xcoord = xleft + (x - xmin)*(xright - xleft)/(xmax - xmin);
```

Similar approach will net you correct values for the Y axis.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!. just one more tweek on this suppose if I divide X-axis in terms of 5 ticks, and each tick falls in b/w xright and xleft. what change, I can make in the above formula

Comment: You first determine your ticks' coordinates in native, they will be `xmin+(xmax-xmin)*currentTick/numberOfTicks` and then use them to determine where would that tick be placed. No changes to formula is required.